# Calculating Total based on Different Discount Rates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I’m trying to calculate the total contract value on a list of projects with different monthly rates and terms (#months). Basically you get a nice discount if the term is longer than 24 months however the discount is capped at $1,000 (you can’t discount more than $1,000) 
0-24 months:Full Price
25-48 months:50% of the full price (capped at $1,000)
49 onwards:25% of the full price (capped at $1,000)

Attached is my spreadsheet and the calculated total works well for some monthly rates but the formula doesn’t work well for lower monthly amounts. I have two columns, Calculated Total and Desired Total (what the total should be). Any idea how I can fix the Calculated Total Formula to get the desired total?  Thank you

```
Amount  Term    Calculated Total    Desired Total
1500    68         $74,000          $80,000 
1000    48         $36,000          $48,000 
4000    36         $120,000         $120,000 
3000    30         $81,000          $81,000 
2000    27         $51,000          $51,000 
4000    120        $216,000         $216,000    




NumMonths   Base    Discount
0           0       1.00 
24          24      0.50 
48          36      0.25
```

Formula:

```
=A2*VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$H$4,2)+A2*(B2-VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$F$4,1))*IF((A2*VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$H$4,3))<1000,1000/A2,VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$H$4,3))
```

Comment: Can you give an sample calculation how you reach one of your desired values? I have no idea how you got to $80,000 the $1500/68 term.

Comment: @VBAPete Sorry there was a typo on the total should be $78,000 (I corrected the number above). Here is how I got to it:                          Monthly Amount=$1,500
Term=68 Months
Month 0-24=$1,500*24=$36,000
Month 25-48=$1,000(this s/b Amount*50% but capped at $1,000)*23 =$23,000
Month 49-68=$1,000 (this should be Amount *25% but capped at $1,000)*19=$19,000
Total=$78,000

Comment: Got it, but then $80,000 is actually correct, because you have 68 terms, not 66 terms.

Comment: @VBAPete Great! Works exactly as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear @user6437637

Comment: Just realized an error in my formula and updated it. Now it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get to a solution I changed the setup of your sheet slightly (beginning, end, discount and max. discount):

[image]

In order to get to your solution, you just have to multiply the different tiers with the terms for each tier. I used **IF functions** to do this:

```
IF(B2>$G$2,$G$2,B2)*IF(A2*(1-$H$2)<$F$7,$F$7,A2*(1-$H$2))+IF(B2>$G$3,$G$3-$G$2,IF(B2-$G$2<0,0,B2-$G$2))*IF(A2*(1-$H$3)<$F$7,$F$7,A2*(1-$H$3))+IF(B2-$G$3>0,B2-$G$3,0)*IF(A2*(1-$H$4)<$F$7,$F$7,A2*(1-$H$4))
```